# css text highlighting

Tags: css, highlighting, html

Been a while since I had a CSS related problem but here I am. to cut a long story short I want to highlight text with a gradient background which I have managed to achieve using the `<span>` tag and setting a background image onto it. The problem is it startes to get a bit trippy and breaks when the text goes on to a new line.

I have managed to fix it but the HTML is horrible and I don't like compromising HTML code for style purposes as a rule.

The best way to describe this is just to show you.

http://jsfiddle.net/sambeckhamdesign/2HSqh/11/

The top `<li>` is the good HTML with the broken style and the botom `<li>` is how it's supposed to look but with awful HTML markup.

Any solutions obviously appreciated. Don't mind using Javascript or jQuery but I'd rarther do it in CSS if I could.

Ta pets :)

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not work. The image URL is protected and it is unlikely that you are able to share the credentials with us.

Comment: the image urls in your jsfiddle are causing the browser to throw up login requests for your server. You'd be better off just putting a background colour in the jsfiddle example, without a background image. (also, if it's just a gradient as described in your question, you could use CSS3 gradients for it).

Comment: @Spudley: A color is not sufficient, because it is all about that image. @Sam: You should upload it somewhere else and fix the URL.

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot I'd protected the directory. Moving it now.

Comment: Moved over, sorry about that.

Comment: You need to update the demo link in your question. It's still pointing to broken images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I could se to do this in the end was to use the `<span>` tag. I hate doing this and try to avoid it when I can but it needed to be used in this case. See the updated JS fiddle in the question for how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you the css hacks working only for **firefox** and **safari**

```
::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

Reference:

#### http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-astonishing-css-hacks-and-techniques

Hope this help :)

Comment: Cheers but this is for selected text. I want it to highlight a header whether it's selected or not. Please see the example

Answer (score 0):

The only method (that does not need extra markup) that i can think of would be to use a repeating background-image that has exactly the height of a line. This should work properly and fast if your line-height is constant. All other approaches are likely to be quite slow or bulky.

Comment: It's a horizontal gradient I'm afraid, and the padding is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this provides what you want

```
ul#container li.hilight {
    padding:3px 20px;
    background:url('http://www.sambeckhamdesign.com/_images/rain_1.jpg') left repeat-y #c06;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

and

```
<li class="hilight">
        This is how the text should look
    <br />
        but the HTML markup is messy
</li>
```